# Is there a difference between initializing a variable in the default constructor or inline?

Tags: c#

I've found a few related questions in Java, but none for C#, so please forgive any duplicates.

Short and sweet, whats the difference? Is there any?

```
public static class Foo
{
    public static List<Bar> Bars;

    static Foo()
    {
        Bars = new List<Bar>();
    }
}

public static class Foo
{
    public static List<Bar> Bars = new List<Bar>();
}
```

See the comment by @Nick G for the answer to the case of non-static classes. I'd still like to know if it affects static classes any differently.

<strike>Now they don't have to be static either. What about this case?</strike>

```
public class Foo
{
    public List<Bar> Bars;

    public Foo()
    {
        Bars = new List<Bar>();
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public List<Bar> Bars = new List<Bar>();
}
```

Comment: According to [this](http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/constructors.html), the difference is that instance initializers run first, then the constructor runs. The docs for [static field initialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645758(v=vs.71).aspx) and [instance field initialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645759(v=vs.71).aspx) both indicate that the fields are initialized before the constructor. Also read [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/02/15/why-do-initializers-run-in-the-opposite-order-as-constructors-part-one/) for inheritance info.

Comment: I don't think this answers your static question completely, but may help: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Beforefieldinit.aspx

Comment: check this [article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Beforefieldinit.aspx) there is slight significance to existence of static constructor.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not,

According to the `IL`, static inline initializer uses constructors, see what happened:

**1) static inline initializer:**

```
static class SomeClass
{
    public static string strField = "Some String";

    static SomeClass()
    {

    }
}
```

and the `IL`:

```
.method private hidebysig specialname rtspecialname static 
        void  .cctor() cil managed
{
  // Code size       12 (0xc)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldstr      "Some String"
  IL_0005:  stsfld     string forStackoverflow.SomeClass::strField
  IL_000a:  nop
  IL_000b:  ret
} // end of method SomeClass::.cctor
```

**2) constructor:**

```
static class SomeClass
{
    public static string strField;

    static SomeClass()
    {
        strField = "Some String";
    }
}
```

and the `IL`:

```
.method private hidebysig specialname rtspecialname static 
        void  .cctor() cil managed
{
  // Code size       12 (0xc)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldstr      "Some String"
  IL_0006:  stsfld     string forStackoverflow.SomeClass::strField
  IL_000b:  ret
} // end of method SomeClass::.cctor
```

so, from the compiler view-sight, no, there is no difference.

Comment: static constructor is in question here

Comment: @Rafal: OK, I changed the test and update the answer

Comment: and you are not correct, read the article by Jon Skeet.